# Why I my React Project goes into infinite loop and keep rendering pokemons on the window?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I run npm start react goes into infinite loop and keeps showing me the same Pokemons again and again. I want to see each pokemon only one time on the screen.

I also got the following error in the console:

> Encountered two children with the same key, `6`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Board from './sub-main/Board';

function Main(Props) {

    const [pokemonList, setPokemonList] = useState(['mewtwo', 'mew', 'arceus', 'rayquaza', 'lugia', 'alakazam', 'ditto', 'gengar', 'charizard', 'dragonite', 'blastoise', 'gyarados'])

  return (
    <div>
        <Board pokemonList={pokemonList}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

This is Board.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import '../styles/board.css'
function Board(props) {
    
    const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        
        const getPokemon = async (pokemon, index) => {
            const response = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon}/`);
            const data = await response.json();
            const pokemonData = { id: index, name: pokemon, url: data.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default}
            console.log(pokemonData)
            setPokemons(pokemons => pokemons.concat(pokemonData))
        }
      
        props.pokemonList.forEach((pokemon, index) => {
            getPokemon(pokemon,index)
            
        })
    }, [])

    
  return (
    <div id='board'>
        {pokemons.map((pokemon) => {
            return <div key={pokemon.id} className="pokemonCard">
                        <p>{pokemon.name}</p>
                        <img src={pokemon.url} alt={`${pokemon.name} pic`}/>
                   </div>
        })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Board;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking a punt here but it sounds like you're running in React's [Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html); is your app getting bootstrapped something like this?:

```
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

and the warnings you're seeing are due to its [deliberate double-invoking of functional components](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects) to flush out possible issues.

The "same key" warning is an excellent tell-tale that you're doing something not-quite-right however, and in this case I think it's the combination of a `forEach` and `array.concat`. As another guess, I'm thinking you might have done it this way to get your server API calls to fire concurrently?

You want exactly as many `pokemonData` objects as you provide Pokemon names, so `map` is the right tool for the job, and we'll use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for all the API calls to resolve before atomically updating state, rather than `concat`ing things:

```
// Pull this helper function outside of your component
const getPokemon = async (pokemon, index) => {
  const response = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon}/`);
  const data = await response.json();
  const pokemonData = {
    id: index,
    name: pokemon,
    url: data.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default
  };
  console.log(pokemonData);
  return pokemonData;
};

function Board(props) {
  const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadPokemons = async () => {
      const pokemonDataPromises = props.pokemonList.map((pokemon, index) => 
     {
        return getPokemon(pokemon, index);
      });

      const pokemonData = await Promise.all(pokemonDataPromises);
      setPokemons(pokemonData);
    };
    loadPokemons();
  }, [props.pokemonList]);

   ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing setState on each iteration of `props.pokemonList`, React won't batch the state updates in async operations which leads to inifinite re-render.

Try to set the state after resolving all the values using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getPokemon = async (pokemon, index) => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon}/`);
    const data = await response.json();
    const pokemonData = { id: index, name: pokemon, url: data.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default }
    return pokemonData
  }

  const pokemonPromisesArr = props.pokemonList.map((pokemon, index) => getPokemon(pokemon, index))
  Promise.all(pokemonPromisesArr).then(pokemonArr => setPokemons(pokemonArr))
}, [])
```